# How to fix setInterval in React?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I'm trying to make a simonSays game in React, but can't figure out how to set the interval with the componentDidMound(). Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated

https://codepen.io/oscicen/pen/rooLXY

```
// Play specific step
playStep(step) {
    this.setState({ clickClass: "button hover" });
    this.sounds[step].play();
    setTimeout(function(){
        this.setState({ clickClass: "button" });
    }, 300);
}

// Show all steps
showSteps() {
    this.setState({ gameConsole: this.state.round });
    let num = 0;
    let moves = setInterval(function(){
        this.playStep(this.state.steps[num]);
        this.setState({ gameConsole: "Wait..." });
        num++;
        if (num >= this.state.steps.length) {
            this.setState({ gameConsole: "Repeat the steps!" });
            clearInterval(moves);
        }
    }, 600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using normal function in setTimeout and setInterval you need to bind the function or change it to arrow function so that you get this context inside the function and setState will work

Here is updated code for your ref

```
   playStep(step) {
       this.setState({ clickClass: "button hover" });
       this.sounds[step].play();
       setTimeout(function(){
           this.setState({ clickClass: "button" });
       }.bind(this), 300);
   }

   // Show all steps
   showSteps() {
        this.setState({ gameConsole: this.state.round });
        let num = 0;
        let moves = setInterval(function(){
       this.playStep(this.state.steps[num]);
       this.setState({ gameConsole: "Wait..." });
       num++;
       if (num >= this.state.steps.length) {
           this.setState({ gameConsole: "Repeat the steps!" });
           clearInterval(moves);
       }
     }.bind(this), 600);
  }
```

Also you have couple of functions declared inside component which does setState so you need those function to either bind manually in constructor or change it to arrow function

Here is updated codepen demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOPyVy

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks! I'm still have a problem with here on the playSound method, the second if is not functioning, if u can take a look I appreciate. Sorry big noob here.

Comment: Fixed it width a callback function after updating state. Sorry for dumb questions.

Comment: Sorry Not sure what does the functionality do inside play sound method. How can I help

Answer (score 0):

```
this
```

isn't known inside callback function.
use `.bind(this)` everytime you need to access `this` in deeper scopes. e.g.:

```
let moves = setInterval(function(){
    this.playStep(this.state.steps[num]);
    this.setState({ gameConsole: "Wait..." });
    num++;
    if (num >= this.state.steps.length) {
        this.setState({ gameConsole: "Repeat the steps!" });
        clearInterval(moves);
    }
}.bind(this), 600)
```